# Since we have ES6 modules, should we look back on AMD, CommonJS etc..?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, es6-modules

Being new to modules, I am trying understand how it should be used in browsers.

I was trying an example where I have two es6 modules in separate files. I transpiled the files using Babel as it is not yet supported in most of the browsers. Initially my understanding was like, babel alone was enough to use modules. Then I got this error - import/export are not defined which eventually lead me to learn about javascript module specs like **AMD**, **commonjs** etc... and the need for module loaders to load the module and I could get the picture of it a little bit.

Even after transpiling using Babel, we definitely need respective module loaders to load the modules. For **AMD**, something like **requirejs** or **curljs**, for **ES6 modules**, it can be **rollup.js** etc... Previously it seemed like **AMD** was used extensively. Since **ES6 module** specs are now confirmed, going forward we can just use **es6 modules** with **rollup.js** without looking back at other module specs right? Or should I consider other module specs as well? If so, what are the useful features that are available in other modules specs that are not handled in **ES6 Modules**?

Comment: Question seems a bit broad, perhaps narrow it down a little bit to a specific framework or what issue you have with using your current module solution. I believe going forward ES6 modules is the most common way now a days since Node.js will soon support it aswell if it doesn't already. Here's decent information from the [Mozilla team](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: If you don't care about IE11 and others like UC Browser you can use native modules without Babel: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module :) But the most preferred way today is to use WebPack. You transpile all modules to ES5 and WebPack put them into one big bundle. Try it